# Deleting a File using Remove - C++

Tags: c++, file-io

I'm relatively new to C ++, and I want to know how to delete a File - based on passing it a directory.I've tried to do this, but it doesn't work.
Code:

```
    remove (".\\Players\\" + getPlayerUsername() + "\\Balance.txt");
```

Error:

```
    11  IntelliSense: no instance of overloaded function "remove" matches the argument list
        argument types are: (std::string)
```

I am using Visual Studio 2013 (which I loath).

Thank you :-)
KJ

Comment: what does the function getPlayerUsername returns?

Comment: Position the cursor in the word "remove" and press F1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to

```
remove ((".\\Players\\" + getPlayerUsername() + "\\Balance.txt").c_str());
```

**===Edit===**

The warning showed you that your expression evaluated to `std::string` while remove requires `const char*`. `std::string` has a method `.c_str()` which returns `const char*` pointer to your string.

Comment: knew it would be something simple like this! Thank you.